# Heroku deployment failing at Shippable - asking to login to heroku

Tags: git, heroku, shippable-ci

I am doing some POC on Shippable to deploy simple node web app to heroku via Shippable. I have tried many options, but could not make it successful. My git repo with shippable.yml at https://github.com/somenathghosh/shippable-node.git.

The build is failing at heroku login.

```
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins... done
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email:
```

I have added shippable ssh-key to heroku account, added heroku API to yml file, installed heroku toolbelt - but no luck. Nowhere I find any solution for this. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't make it work yet, but this can be useful

```
    before_install:
   - which heroku || wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
   - ls /tmp/ssh # to find the ssh keys
   - ssh-add -l
   - for FILE in `ls /tmp/ssh/*`; do echo "Public key for $FILE"; ssh-keygen -y -f $FILE; done
```

the documentation is out of date and the ssh keys are not longer in .ssh folder

of course this will fail de ci, but in the console you can find the ssh key